# PL/SQL graph checker

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there exist any way to write shortest Path Search Algorithm (graps, Dijkstra) using pl/sql? It needs to be done very simple and easy to understand for absolute zero beginner in plsql.

Task data

```
('Boston', 'Chicago', 6);
('Boston', 'Montreal', 5);
('Chicago ','SanJose', 2);
('Detroit', 'Toronto', 4); 
('NewYork', 'Chicago', 2);
('LosAngeles', 'Boston', 8); 
('LosAngeles', 'Detroit', 7);
('LosAngeles', 'NewYork', 6); 
('Toronto', 'Montreal', 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There surely is, it's already been done:
http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/shortest_distance.html

I doubt there is a "very simple and easy to understand" way for an absolute zero beginner. Absolute zero beginners should lower their ambitions and wait till their skill catches up with the complexities of implementing a non-trivial algorithm in a language they are not familiar with. Have you implemented Dijkstra's algorithm in another language already?

Google searches are also highly recommended for this type of questions; it took me two seconds to find the link above.  https://www.google.com/

Comment: Absolutely agree about ambitions. It's no surprise that the linked solution was written by Frank Zhou; Frank's one of the smartest SQL wranglers around. Even SQL veterans take a deep breath before plunging in to some of his solutions :)